# How to add nodes in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

I want to transfer the following picture to LaTeX, which is nearly complete. However I fail to add nodes/markings for h_0,025 and h_0,975 like in the picture. Whenever I add \node ... LaTeX just crashes and doesnt stop loading. Does someone have an idea how to do it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
 }

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=-4:4, samples=100,
  axis lines*=left, %xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, width=12cm,
  xtick={0.5}, ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major
  ]  
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-4:4] {gauss(0.5,1)} 
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [fill=white, draw=none, domain=-1.1:2.1] {gauss(0.5,1)} 
  \closedcycle;

  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(0.5,1)};

  \draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex](axis cs:4,0) -- node [fill=white] 
  {\small{0,025 Qantil}} (axis cs:2.1,0);
  \end{axis}

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't provide the code that fails (in commented form) so we don't exactly know what you tried to do and so could guess why your code could crash LaTeX.

There are plenty of ways how to add the labels and lines you wanted to add. Here I present a way using normal `xticks` to place the labels together with the small "lines outside the axis and drawing extra vertical lines upwards from the x-axis. To place the label in the "middle area" I use a normal node. For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher so one don't has to prefix TikZ
        % coordinates by `axis cs:'
        compat=1.11,
        % (moved declared function here ...
        /pgf/declare function={
            % ... and added argument `\x'.
            gauss(\x,\mean,\std) = 1/(\std*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\mean)^2)/(2*\std^2));
            % Also created a dummy short version of your used function)
            MyGauss(\x) = gauss(\x,0.5,1);
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=5cm,
        width=12cm,
        no markers,
        domain=-4:4,
        samples=101,
        axis lines*=left,
        every axis y label/.style={
            at=(current axis.above origin),
            anchor=south,
        },
        every axis x label/.style={
            at=(current axis.right of origin),
            anchor=west,
        },
        % added the other two values here ...
        xtick={-1.1,0.5,2.1},
        % ... and stated the corresponding labels
        xticklabels={
            $h_{0,025}$,
            $\pgfmathprintnumber{0.5}$,
            $h_{0,975}$
        },
        ytick=\empty,
        % place the ticks only outside ...
        tick align=outside,
        % ... using this length
        major tick length=2mm,
        % this is to set the base line of the normal and extra ticks to
        % the same level/height
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
        % this is to use a comma as decimal separator
        /pgf/number format/use comma,
        enlargelimits=false,
        clip=false,
        axis on top,
    ]
        % filled areas at the sides
        \addplot [fill=cyan!20,draw=none,domain=-4:-1.1] {MyGauss(\x)}
            \closedcycle;
        \addplot [fill=cyan!20,draw=none,domain=2.1:4]   {MyGauss(\x)}
            \closedcycle;

        % line plot of function
        \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {MyGauss(\x)};

        % ----------
        % draw the vertical lines at the ticks
        \draw [help lines]
            (-1.1,0) -- ($ (-1.1,0)!1.5!(-1.1,{MyGauss(-1.1)}) $)
            ( 2.1,0) -- ($ ( 2.1,0)!1.5!( 2.1,{MyGauss( 2.1)}) $)
            ( 0.5,0) -- (0.5,{MyGauss(0.5)})
        ;

        % node in "middle" area
        \node at (0.5,{MyGauss(0.5)/2}) {\pgfmathprintnumber{0.95}};

        % (shifted this a bit more down so the text isn't that near to each other)
        \draw [yshift=-9mm, latex-latex] (axis cs:4,0)
            -- node [fill=white]
                {\small{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{0.025} Quantil}}
                    (axis cs:2.1,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you very much, that solves my problem perfectly! Could you by chance also recommend me a way to "label" the white area as the 95% confidence interval (like in my original drawing)?

Comment: @Clemetti, sure, have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: When this answer solves your question you could -- besides [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score when you have gathered 15 reputation points) -- also [accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Is there also an easy way to extend the extra x ticks below the x axis? I achieved it with setting the major grid length to -1mm, however I would prefer to have the grid above the axis until 15mm (like in your example) and at the same time roughly 1mm below the axis (like in my orginal drawing).

Comment: @Clemetti, I guess only doing this with the ticks isn't possible, because when you want to draw the ticks inside *and* outside you would have to use `tick align=center` which implicitly means that they are drawn *symmetrically* inside and outside which of course isn't what you want. So I had to modify my code a bit more to achieve your desired result ...